# C Pointer Assignment

Tags: c, pointers

So I was playing around with some pointer today and ran into a rather confusing predicament. I use C a lot but couldn't seem to figure out why this wouldn't work maybe its just one of those days.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void subr(int* numero){
    int* newNum = malloc(sizeof(int));
    (*newNum) = 5;
    numero = newNum;
    printf("%d\n", *numero);
}

int main(){
    int* number;
    printf("%p\n", (void *) number);

    subr(number);
    if(number == NULL)
        printf("Not assigned\n");
    else
        printf("%d\n", *number);
}
```

So I create a pointer in main, pass it into a function which allocates space and then assigns it back to the pointer passed in. Why is it that everytime I run this I get that the pointer is still null?

Comment: in your case you need pointer to pointer, so `int** numero` and then `*numero = newNum;` and `subr(&number);` or simpler a reference to pointer, so just `int*& numero` and no more changes

Comment: No free, undefined behaviour in line 2 of main etc.

Comment: And your pointer is NULL by pure chance.

Comment: @jpw: at the time I posted the comment, the question had C++ tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that this code does not work is that C is a pass-by-value language. If you wish to modify anything, you have to pass a pointer to it:

```
void subr(int** numero){
    int* newNum = malloc(sizeof(int));
    (*newNum) = 5;
    *numero = newNum;
    printf("%d\n", **numero);
}

int main(){
    int* number = NULL; // <<== Need to initialize it
    printf("%p\n", (void *) number);

    subr(&number);
    if(number == NULL)
        printf("Not assigned\n");
    else
        printf("%d\n", *number);
    free(number); // <<== Don't forget to free what's malloc-ed
}
```

Comment: Gah, so used to passing in function ptrs that I was automatically thinking it was ptr address being passed in. Thanks, silly oversight!